# Connecting an Ubuntu machine to a windows network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, samba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connecting a Ubuntu machine to a windows network](https://superuser.com/questions/61832/connecting-a-ubuntu-machine-to-a-windows-network)

I am in the process of installing Ubuntu (9.0) onto a spare machine. I want to make the Ubuntu machine a part of my Windows network (which for the moment), consists of a single XP machine.

I want to do the following on my "network" (initially, it will be 1 Ubuntu machine and 1 XP machine) - and I am seeking some help on how to go about achieving these goals:

1. Share a printer, so that both machines can print documents
2. Be able to copy (*.cpp and *.php) source files from the XP machine to the Ubuntu machine 
   Note: this is likely to be a one of requirement
3. Maintain a svn repository on the (newer) XP machine and use it (i.e. commit to the repository etc) from the Ubuntu machine
4. Transfer binary files from the XP machine to the Ubuntu machine

Note: The files though binary (and written on the XP box), will be read using the same library (but compiled for Linux), on the Ubuntu box.

Note2 : I will need to transfer these files daily

Comment: this should be on superuser.com

Comment: No, it should be on ServerFault. Don't just dump things. Once it gets dumped, it's harder to fix because there are fewer mods on SU, so please try to dump it in the right place the first time.

Comment: k, I moved it - how may I delete the question now ...?

Comment: oh, for f*cks sake! - where should I post this question ... everyone seems to have a different opinion  :( ?!

Comment: @skyeagle: please calm down .. it is confusing at first, but not your fault, and not a major fault/problem anyway ..

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. Look into CUPS
2. You'll need a drive or partition using FAT32